# Fill the secondary diagonal with respect to a point?

Tags: python

The problem is that I have a point, say `P = (p1,p2)`, in a 2x2 numpy array in Python. Now using the point `P` I want to fill the all the entries in the secondary diagonal passing through with that point.
So what it looks like is:

```
arr = [0,0,0,0,0
       0,0,0,0,0
       0,0,0,0,0
       0,0,0,0,0
       0,0,0,0,0]
 
 P = (1,4)

arr = [0,0,0,0,0
       0,0,0,0,1
       0,0,0,1,0
       0,0,1,0,0
       0,1,0,0,0]
```

or let's say `P = (3,0)`:

```
arr = [0,0,0,1,0
       0,0,1,0,0
       0,1,0,0,0
       1,0,0,0,0
       0,0,0,0,0]
```

The array with ones is the final result required.

Comment: What have you tried? A simple loop incrementing the rows and decrementing the columns seems to be an easy way...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so the algorithm I am trying was to first mark the position on which I want the diagonal then extract all indeces and fill those indecies with the numbers I desire. so using diagonal in the numpy package I would get the diagonal which had the marked point. But that is where i stopped because I couldn't figure out how to get indecies and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the array using the indices and feed it to `np.fliplr` and `p.fill_diagonal` to get the reversed diagonal

```
arr = np.zeros(shape=(5, 5), dtype=int)
p = (...)
np.fill_diagonal(np.fliplr(arr[p[0]:, :p[1]+1]), 1)
print(arr)
```

Output

```
p = 1, 4

[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]]


p = 0, 3

[[0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```